How to store Bitcoin safely?
I'm starting to invest in Bitcoin now, regretting not having started in 2017 when I heard about it. I still have little money invested and it doesn't make sense to invest in a hardwallet at the moment.
That's why I'm using an Android phone that I don't use daily as a cold wallet. I generated two wallets using manual entropy with RPG data, one wallet has 12 words and the other has 24 words. And I'm going to use a pass-pharse on each one of them.
My question is: Is there really a need for a seed-pharse with 24 words or 12 is safe enough (I'll use pass-pharse together).
In addition to the pass-pharse, is there anything else to protect my Bitcoins?

Would it be fair to say that your main question is "Are 24-word seed phrases safer than 12-word seed phrases?"?
